# IoT Edge Module with more than 1 input fails. Test with "input1" and "input2" in one module does not succeed

Tags: azure-iot-edge

An IoT Edge Module in C# can have how many message inputs? The examples all show "input1" but nothing beyond that. Documentation does not mention anything beyond "input1".

I am trying to use multiple inputs in a single IoT Edge C# module but am not sure how to do it. The sample program sets up "input1" connected to an input message handler called PipeMessage. When using that module with default routing all works well. When trying to add a second input message handler and call the input "input2" and add some routing, nothing goes through. How do we go about setting up more than one input in a C# IoT Edge module?

The program.cs Task Init() sets up the input message handler with a call back method called PipeMessage. I duplicate this code and change the names of the second input but no go.

```
 static async Task Init()
 {
        AmqpTransportSettings amqpSetting = new AmqpTransportSettings(TransportType.Amqp_Tcp_Only);
        ITransportSettings[] settings = { amqpSetting };

        // Open a first connection to the Edge runtime
        ModuleClient ioTHubModuleClient = await ModuleClient.CreateFromEnvironmentAsync(settings);
        await ioTHubModuleClient.OpenAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("IoT Hub module client initialized.");

        // Register callback to be called when a message is received by the module on input1
        await ioTHubModuleClient.SetInputMessageHandlerAsync("input1", PipeMessage, ioTHubModuleClient);

        // Open a second connection to the Edge runtime
        ModuleClient ioTHubModuleClient2 = await ModuleClient.CreateFromEnvironmentAsync(settings);
        await ioTHubModuleClient2.OpenAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("IoT Hub module client initialized.");

        // Register callback to be called when a message is received by the module on input2
        await ioTHubModuleClient2.SetInputMessageHandlerAsync("input2", PipeMessage2, ioTHubModuleClient);
}
```

`

and the routes are as follows:

```
    "routes": {
        "CSharpFilter2ToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/CSharpFilter2/outputs/* INTO $upstream",
        "sensor1ToCSharpFilter2": "FROM /messages/modules/tempSensor1/outputs/temperatureOutput INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/CSharpFilter2/inputs/input1\")",
        "sensor2ToCSharpFilter2": "FROM /messages/modules/tempSensor2/outputs/temperatureOutput INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/CSharpFilter2/inputs/input2\")"
      },
```

What am I doing wrong?

More specifically, what are we supposed to do for handling more than one input in an IoT Edge Module?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to (or should) create a second ModuleClient. Instead simply call SetInputMessageHandlerAsync() multiple times:

```
ModuleClient ioTHubModuleClient = await ModuleClient.CreateFromEnvironmentAsync(settings);
await ioTHubModuleClient.OpenAsync();   

await ioTHubModuleClient.SetInputMessageHandlerAsync("input1", PipeMessage1, ioTHubModuleClient);
await ioTHubModuleClient.SetInputMessageHandlerAsync("input2", PipeMessage2, ioTHubModuleClient);
```

Comment: Thank you, good answer. Looking back I can see the question was not well done but you handled it with tact. Thank you.